# I dont understand why output is 65 here?

Tags: c++

This the code i am having doubt with.I am getting 65 as output.I need an explanation regarding how it works.

```
#include<iostream>
#define combine(a,b,c) a##b##c
int main()
{
    std::cout<<combine(2+2,3+3,5+5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the macro expands is `2+23+35+5`.

Comment: The "Why?" is quite easy to answer (and I did). Could you specify what output you are expecting? What is the goal of your unique macro construct? If you clarify that, answer might solve your misunderstanding. If you however expect answer which provide solutions for what you are trying to achieve you will have to ask that separatly (now that there is an answer to the question as initially asked).

Comment: If you want to concatenate strings, try`#define combine(a,b,c) (#a#b#c)`

Comment: @ZhuSong Your contribution is appreciated. Please consider making an answer. If you want to clarify OPs goals first, then please ask more explicitly. "Do you intend to concatenate strings?" or maybe "Do you expect as output '2+2 3+3 5+5'?" (or whatever guess you want to clarify).

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 3):

The macro expands to

`2+23+35+5`

Now it should be clear why the result is 65.

Answer (score 3):

The `##` operator performs token concatenation, it essentially "glues" the tokens on either side together.

Your macro replaces `combine(a,b,c)` with `a##b##c` which essentially means `abc`, thus translating your code you get:

`std::cout<<combine(2+2,3+3,5+5);` that becomes `std::cout<<2+23+35+5` (think of it as `two+twothree+threefive+five` if that makes more sense to you), since the tokens get "glued" together, and the result is obviously the same as doing `std::cout<<65`

That's why you get `65` as your output

Comment: Admittedly I actually thought that to be your meaning. I intended to kind of "provoke" you into seeing the possible misunderstanding. ;-)